# Understanding a clause starting with "you can barely move for..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

**[SOURCE](http://documents.mx/documents/unit-3-relationships.html)**

> In parts of South America, you can barely move for beautiful people chipping their nail polish on endangered hardwoods, and, in Africa, cuddling up to wild animals. Tracy Ward, the actress and now Marchioness of Worcester, started trying to save the tropical rain forest after a stint on a detective TV series. As she tellingly explained, "I had never really had the time or the knowledge, and suddenly when I had no work I realised there was a problem."

I don't really understand what the sentence "you can barely move for beautiful people...." means.

Comment: _For_ here means _"because of the"_. It is idiomatic English. The sense is that there are so many beautiful people crowding such places that the writer can "hardly move".

Comment: Thank you very much but what does this part mean? "beautiful people chipping their nail polish on endangered hardwoods, and, in Africa, cuddling up to wild animals".

Comment: If you don't know what _beautiful people_, _nail polish_ and _hardwood floors_ mean, or what happens to nail polish when the wearer _chips_ it, or what _endangered_ and _cuddling_ mean, you may be trying to read material that exceeds your current understanding of English. It would be better for you to start with simple texts at this stage of your learning.

Comment: It is a text in our course book. A text by Margaret Driscoll. It is a very long text that i understand but this one it is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I know the meaning of cuddle. I know hardwood floor nail polish and chip but i can't get the general idea.my problem is not about words. I can't understand why the writer is talking about these.

Comment: The writer refers ironically to the beautiful people and their promotion of conservation as a good cause.

Comment: I want to be sure you understand: the writer is expressing _irony_ and _cynicism_. Those are words worth looking up in your English dictionary, especially if you're going to read relatively "advanced", topical and idiomatic things like this.

Comment: Yes i know the meaning of these two words. Thank you so much for caring and being so kind☺

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps here:

1. As P.E. says, "for" means "because of the."
2. "You can barely move [because of the]..." means "there are really a lot of..." The metaphor is that those people form a very thick crowd, but that isn't literally true.
3. In context, the "beautiful people chipping their nails on endangered hardwoods" are creating the appearance of saving the rain forest but are not actually helping, probably because, like Tracy Ward, they don't have the knowledge.

So, all together, the sense is: in parts of South America and Africa, there are many people trying to look like environmentalists while doing no good.

Answer (score 0):

Just breaking it down...

> "you can barely move for...."

This is a common expression, sometimes literal but also used as an exaggeration, to describe or imply a crowded or cluttered situation. It could be cluttered by other people, or objects.

**For example:**

> You can barely move in this warehouse for all the boxes.

---

The term:

> "beautiful people"

This is often used to describe a certain *type* of person - fashionable, glamorous, or privileged people. When used this way it is usually *pejorative*. Always consider context, however. I would not instantly assume it was pejorative - some might describe others as "beautiful people" out of genuine admiration. But in your quote the writer refers to these people "chipping their nail polish" which does sound like they are mocking people who would wear nail polish to visit a rainforest.